# Validating textpane for the range

Tags: java, swing, validation, jtextpane, jformattedtextfield

How I can validate a `JTextPane` when I enter any value in the text pane which is outside the specified range?  I want to change the text pane to red to indicate that user has not entered the correct value and the user shall again enter the value in the textpane.

How I can validate that?

Comment: More info needed actually. Do you want the error displayed as and when the user types? Or after he has entered the text and the focus is lost? A SSCCE will be helpful. Here's how you can write one: http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2):

This situation probably calls for a [`JFormattedTextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html).  For further details and working code, see [How to Use Formatted Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html) in the tutorial.

Comment: Note that I can most likely swap the 'probably' for definitely' or a better strategy if you post an SSCCE that gives more idea of what you are trying to validate (what is valid, what is not etc.).

Comment: this is answer for JSpinner, isn't it